# MySQL SELECTING DATES

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying some data from MySQL table, one of the column has a datatype DATETIME. Now when I do query, it includes an annoying `00:00:00` time. How can I exclude this time part when doing a select?

Answer (score 2):

use `DATE`

```
SELECT DATE(columnName)
FROM....
```

or `DATE_FORMAT`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d');
```